# Static method used in a class

Tags: java, android

I have a static method(addItem) in a class, why do we need to wrap the addItem(..) uses with static parenthesis? why do we need the static word? 
TNX

```
public class Something{

 static {

        addItem(new DummyItem("1", "A"));
        addItem(new DummyItem("2", "B"));
        addItem(new DummyItem("3", "C"));
    }

    private static void addItem(DummyItem item) {
       ......
    }


}
```

Comment: That is static initialization block.https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html

Comment: When do you need this method invocation to happen? BTW we don't have to wrap `addItem` in `static{ ... }` block, but we need to invoke it at *some point* of `Something` object existence. So which point should it be?

Comment: @Pshemo - I'm pretty sure the init needs to be in a static block specifically because the Something object may not exist (except for it's static components)

Comment: @KevinDTimm It can be static, but I can also remove `static` keyword and it will compile fine (it will just mean that this code will be executed when each instance of `Something` is created, not after `Something` class is being loaded, or more precisely initialized). It all depends on what OP wants to achieve.

Comment: @Pshemo - I'm guessing (assuming) that the OP wants it for testing purposes, in which case he's filling the array (adding items) @ static time, not creation - You're right though, we're both unsure/unknowing of the purpose by OP

Comment: @Almog could you [edit] your question and explain why you think that we need to wrap the addItem in static parenthesis? Also what are you trying to achieve with this code?

Answer (score 0):

The static block

```
static {
    ....
}
```

defines a static initializer. The block of code is run exactly once, when the class is initialized. You can call static methods in any method, not just in static intializers. So for example you could also write

```
public void foo() {
    Something.addItem(new DummyItem("1", "A"));
}
```

This code would be called whenever the method foo() was called.

Comment: Thanks, well explained